# Copying the data from MS SQL server to MySQL

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I need to copy all the data from MS SQL server to MySQL server. I am planning to use the Quartz scheduler to perform this. This scheduler will run every night and move the data from MS-SQL-Server to MySQL server. Can anyone please tell if this is fine or is there any other better way to do this?

**Update:**
I need to transfer only one table with 40 columns (from MS SQL server to MySQL)

Comment: Yes, personally I think it's fine, since you are running every night.

Comment: If you don't have a ETL tool that would do this job for you, then create your own cron using `Quartz` to do this job. This is strange because MSSQL offers this kind of tools and you can even create a SQL Server job to execute the ETL. Which MSSQL version are you using?

Comment: As you mentioned `only one table with 40 columns`. `JDBC` is more lightly and quickly to finish the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't involve java unless I absolutely had to: java would be adding no value but would be adding extra complexity.

This is a "DBA" type task that belongs in a script scheduled with cron tab.

If I was implementing it, I would export the source database as an SQL script then import it by running it on the target.

Comment: "java would be adding no value but would be adding extra complexity."  -- quoted for emphasis

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use http://www.talend.com for tasks like that.

**UPDATE**

Talend Open Studio for Data Integration is Opensource, there are some other features which are propietary [details here](http://www.talend.com/products/data-integration)

Comment: It *looks* promising, I'll keep the link for future cases.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Management Studio's "Import Data" task (right-click on the DB name, then tasks) will do most of this for you. Run it from the database you want to copy the data into.

If the tables don't exist it will create them for you, but you'll probably have to recreate any indexes and such. If the tables do exist, it will append the new data by default but you can adjust that (edit mappings) so it will delete all existing data.

I use this all the time and it works fairly well.

by- david

Comment: This comes with MSSQL 2005+. I don't remember the tool that comes with MSSQL 2000.

Answer (score 1):

As PbxMan said, I would use an ETL, but I recommed Pentaho (http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Spoon+User+Guide) which I think is far easier for such simple jobs

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @bohemian - running a job to transfer a single table every night sounds like a great candidate for a cron job (or "scheduled task" if on Windows). Using a framework like Quartz for this task seems like overkill.

There are many solutions for moving data from SQL Server to MySQL, others have listed great solutions such as Talend. If it would benefit you to only transfer certain columns (for example, to avoid leaking [PII](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/personally-identifiable-information-pii.asp)), my product SQLpipe might help, as it transfers the result of a *query*, not an entire table.

Here is a blog post showing how to use the product to [transfer data from SQL Server to MySQL](https://sqlpipe.com/transfer-data-from-sql-server-to-mysql).